# how to join indexes on elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elastic-stack

I have two indexes : **Student**

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and **University** having a onetomany relationship with student

how to declare mappings for university?

Comment: Take a look at "Elastic Common Schema". To some extent it helps you correlate different data sources.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the [Join field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) here, you should really beware of trying to use Elasticsearch as a relational database. It doesn't really support joins without a big performance tax and without some limitations (indexing parent and child into the same shard).

Usually the answer would be to de-normalize the relation. For example, in this case put some of the University fields directly in the Student document, allowing you to search on them directly.